# For an algebraically closed field $k$, an ideal $I$ of $k[x]$ is maximal if and only if $I = (x-c)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

This is an exercise $4.21$ on a page $155$ from a textbook "Algebra: Chapter $0$" by P.Aluffi.

> Let $k$ be an algebraically cloased field, and let $I \subseteq k[x]$ be an ideal. Prove that $I$ is maximal if and only if $I = (x-c)$ for some $c \in k$.

So, I tried to prove that $(x-c)$ is maximal. Assume that $J$ is an ideal of $k[x]$ containing $(x-c)$. We know that if $k$ is a field, then $k[x]$ is a PID. So $J = (f(x))$ for some polynomial $f(x) \in k[x]$.

$(x-c) \subseteq (f(x))$

We know that there is $g(x) \in k[x]$ such that $x-c = f(x)g(x)$. Since $k$ is algebraically closed, $f(x)$ has a root $a \in k$. So a - c = f(a)g(a) = 0$, so $a = c$.

Now we divide $f(x)$ by $(x-c)$ with remainder: $f(x) = q(x)(x-c) + r$. Since $f(c) = r$ and $f(c) = 0, r = 0$. So, $f(x) = q(x)(x-c)$.

What can be done next?

Comment: First assume that $J=(f)$ is not $k[x]$ i.e. $f$ is not a constant. Then using $x-c=f\cdot g$, you can get the degree of $f$ is $1$, so $f=x-c'$ (w.l.o.g. assume that $f$ is a monic) for some $c'\in k$. Since $f$ divides $x-c$, you get $c=c'$.

Comment: This direction is shown in Proposition 4.6 and Example 4.7 of the book.

Answer (score 4):

Let me first answer your question "What can be done next?".

Note that at that point you're still busy proving that $(x - c)$ is maximal. You've established $f(x) = q(x) (x - c)$. So, continuing your argument: $f(x) \in (x - c)$ and therefore $(f(x)) \subseteq (x - c)$. You already had $(x - c) \subseteq (f(x))$, so $(f(x)) = (x - c)$.

One small detail: the ideal $J$ you started with could be equal to $(1)$. You're missing that case at the point that you say "Since $k$ is algebraically closed, $f(x)$ has a root $a \in k$.". Of course, you should assume $J$ to be unequal to $(1)$, and then it is indeed generated by a non-constant $f(x)$.

Now, as can be seen from the other answers and comments, this is a complicated way to prove that $(x - c)$ is maximal. An easier reasoning is as follows: $k[x] / (x - c) \cong k$, so it's a field. Therefore $(x - c)$ is maximal. Note that this also doesn't need $k$ to be algebraically closed.

To prove that all maximal ideals are of the form $(x - c)$, you do need the assumption that $k$ is algebraically closed. So, take a maximal ideal $J$. Because $k[x]$ is a p.i.d., it is of the form $J = (f(x))$ for some $f(x) \in k[x]$. This $f(x)$ is not a constant (because then $J$ would be the whole of $k[x]$), and because $k$ is algebraically closed, it has a root, say $c \in k$. Then $f(x) = q(x) (x - c)$ for some $q(x) \in k[x]$. In particular $f(x) \in (x - c)$, so $J \subseteq (x - c)$. Since $J$ is maximal, $J = (x - c)$.

Comment: Can i ask you two questions? $1)$ How do we prove $f(c) = 0 \Rightarrow f(x) = g(x)(x-c). 2)$ Why $f(x) = q(x)(x-c) \Rightarrow x-c \in ((f(x))$ implications? It has something to do with the fact $(f(x))$ is maximal? I didn't see where you used this.

Comment: You've give the argumentation for $f(c) = 0 \Rightarrow f(x) = g(x) ( x - c )$ yourself: divide $f(x)$ by $x - c$ to get $f(x) =g(x)(x - c) + r$. Here $r$ is a constant because it has degree smaller than that of $x - c$. Then substitute $x = 0$.

Comment: For $f(x) = q(x)(x - c) \Rightarrow x - c \in (f(x))$, that is simply wrong :-(, sorry about that. I've fixed the argument: the point is that $f(x) \in (x - c)$, not that $x - c \in (f(x))$.

Answer (score 3):

Observe that $\;(x-c)\;$ is maximal iff $\;k[x]/(x-c)\;$ is a field, but

$$k[x]/(x-c)\cong k\;,\;\;\text{since the evaluation homomorphism}\;\;\phi(f(x)):=f(c
)$$

is surjective and its kernel is $\;(x-c)\;$

Comment: How can one prove that $\ker \phi = (x-c)$? That is, every polynomial that has $c$ as a root, is of the form $(x-c)g(x)$ for some polynomial $g(x)$.

Comment: Because $\;x-c\;$ is the *minimal* polynomial which has $\;c\;$ as a root and it is thus irredudible, meaning that any polynomial that vanishes on $\;c\;$ is a multiple, in $\;k[x]\;$, of $\;x-c\;$ .

Comment: This shows that $(x - c)$ is maximal, but not why every maximal ideal is of that form.

Answer (score 3):

The maximal ideals in $F[x]$, where $F$ is any field, are of the form
$$
I=(f(x))
$$
where $f\in F[x]$ is an irreducible monic polynomial.

What are the irreducible monic polynomials over an algebraically closed field?

Comment: Why does $f$ need to be monic? It doesn't seem to make any difference since $F$ is a field

Comment: @laflaca Choosing $f$ monic ensure uniqueness of the classification.

Answer (score 0):

Let $J$ be an ideal containing $(x-c)$, $P\in J$ not in $(x-c)$.Divide $P$ by $x-c$, $P=q(x)(x-c)+r$ this implies $r=P-q(x)(x-c)\in J$ $r=0$ since $J$ is not $k[X]$. Contradiction since $P$ is not in $(x-c)$.

On the other hand if $I$ is maximal, $p$ an element of minimal degree>1, write $p=(x-a)(x-b)q(x)$ since $k$ is algebraically closed, $(x-a)$ contains $p$ contradiction with the fact that $I$ is maximal.
So an element of minimal degree of $I$ is of the form $x-c$ if $p\in I$, write $p=q(x-c)+r, r\in k, r=p-q(x-c)\in I$. This implies that $r=0$ since $I$ is distinct of $k[x]$.